# Application running fine then suddenly java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: java

Does anyone know of any reason why I might encounter java.util.MissingResourceException on an application which is running fine with no issues and constantly using this resource bundle, then suddenly gets this error. Simply stopping the app and starting it resolves the error.

So I don't believe it's anything to do with application setup or configuration since its working fine and suddenly happens and resolved by simply stop and start.

```
2016-07-30 17:23:28,343 [TestScheduler_Worker-10]     ERROR (TRIPSPortingTimeUtil.java:63) - Error Loading the file TRIPSB4NConfig.properties
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name TRIPSB4NConfig, locale en_GB
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:724)
```

**UPDATE**
One thing i have observed is that this seems to happen just after i see database transaction timeout and the following error

```
2016-05-26 20:11:25,995 [TestScheduler_Worker-8]     ERROR (SqlHelperBean.java:1829) - Error while getting transaction Id -
weblogic.jdbc.extensions.ConnectionDeadSQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDeadException: 0:weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection. The DBMS driver exception was: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

is it possible that this could have some knock on effect to my resource bundle?

Comment: Are you in fact looking for locale `en_GB`?

Comment: Nope method call is just giving single stiring input `rbCfg=ResourceBundle.getBundle("TRIPSB4NConfig");`

Comment: I am in UK as is my servers

Comment: OK. Is the resource file in the same JAR as the code loading the bundle? Or is it somewhere else in the class path?

Comment: its located in seperate path and added to class path, i ahve put one update in my question.

Comment: I would check for file handle exhaustion ... maxing out open file handles could cause both opening a new DB connection and opening a resource file to fail. The resource file is on the local filesystem, yes?

Comment: Thanks, yeah this was my next line of thinking, that application is consuming many open file desciprtors and reaching OS limit.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle any updates on this? Were you able to solve it? I am facing a similar issue here...

Comment: @jvataman - I didtn get to the bottom of mines it didnt happen again. However what i did find when i started checking through the implementation is that this error is thrown when there is an I/O error. but the actual I/O error is masked by missing resource exception. so I added debug code before and after the call to get bundle. I just try to open the file manually and catch the I/O error printing it log file or printing if the file opens successfully. hopefully i would see the underlying I/O error that get bundle masks.

Comment: @jvataman i done isolated testing of this with a small class i created. For example if the file has wrong permissions. i.E not readable by that user running the JVM process. then missing resource exception is given, but hides the actual I/O error, writing the small debug patch printed to the log in this case the I/O exception of wrong permissions.

Comment: thanks, I'll dig into it. I have a very similar case here where a service runs for weeks then suddenly raises a DB related IO exception followed by MissingRessourceExceptions and complete shutdown... not clear what the reason is.

Comment: Whats your db related I/O exception? is it possible your resource exception is also the same type of I/O error but masked by missing resource?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't need the resource before the error happens. When the application needs it a crash happens.

Can you check your resources files to check if the resource is present or not?

```
TRIPSB4NConfig.properties for language en_GB
```

Comment: The method is being executed many times, I personally wouldnt have set like this i would have made singleton to load the ressource once but i didnt write this. So resource is loaded many hundreds of times per day. and works fine sometimes for months, and then this and only a restart fixes it. no config is changed. also method is called as `rbCfg=ResourceBundle.getBundle("TRIPSB4NConfig");` and this file existso n the file system. As i said it can run fine then hit this issue and simply stopping and restarting works.